# Why does the arc length formula θ = S/R include θ and not tan θ like regular trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, angle, arc-length

The arclength formula, θ = S/R is simliar in format to the trigonometric formula tan θ = opposite / adjacent, where S= opposite, and r = adjacent (although the trigonometric formula is for right angled triangles, it seems to me they show some similarities).

This uses tan, whereas the arclength formula does not.

Why is this the case?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/B0kQdhH.png]

Comment: This formula defines the radian measure of a central angle subtended by an arc of length $s$ in a circle with radius $r$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question... Why is the formula different? Well, because it produces a different result. One formula (with $\tan$) gives you the length of the segment on the tangent, the other gives you the arc, for the same angle. The tangent is (pretty obviously, as the angle grows) bigger than the arc. Why would you expect the same result in the first place?

Comment: Thank you. I guess I just didn't understand why the formulas seemed to look similiar geometrically i.e. S looked similiar to the opposite side and R the adjacent side of a right angled triangle (if we made S straight), but in the   right angle triangle version there is a tan whilst there is no tan for the arclength version.

Is it just a coincidence the formulas look somewhat similiar?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple: $\tan\theta = S/R$ would only apply to a right triangle! This is a sector, which has a curved edge and is not a triangle.

For a wonderful counterexample, consider the angle $\pi$, which corresponds to half a circle. On the unit circle the arc length is $(1)(\pi)=\pi$, but how could this possibly relate to the tangent function?

Answer (score 1):

The spirit of the arc-length formula is the same as that of Thales' theorem. When the radius is $1 $, the arc-length **is** the angle, by definition of an angle. When the radius is $ r $, you have scaled your picture by a factor of $ r $, and every length of every curve is thereby multiplied by a factor of $ r $ in the process, meaning that the arc-length is now $ r\theta $.

As for the tangent - well,  it measures something completely different. But it is a definition rather than a formula that you can prove.